# Remove multiple items from List view except Selected items

Tags: android, android-listview

I am making an android app in which there is one List view. On selecting the particular item for first time, I have changed text color of that item. Multiple selection is allowed for List view. Now there is one text view named "Done". When user clicks on "Done", items which are not selected from List view should be removed. What should I do? Below is my code...

```
tvDone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if( colorRow > 0 )
                    {
                    AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NewFriendList.this).create();
                    builder.setTitle("Save to List");
                    builder.setMessage("Do You Want to Save?");
                    builder.setButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                    {

                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                      {
                          tvEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                          tvClear.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                          tvDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                      }
                    });

                     builder.setButton2("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                     {
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                         {
                             chkText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                             tvEdit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                             tvClear.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                             tvDelete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                         }

                      });
                      builder.show();
                    }

                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Select Friends", 1000).show();
            }
            });

            lvDialog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    checked = lvDialog.getCheckedItemPositions();
                    chkText = (CheckedTextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.txt);

                    if(checked.get(arg2))
                    {
                        chkText.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
                        colorRow ++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chkText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        colorRow--;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do such actions is to use [Action mode](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/selection.html) of action bar.

Anyways, Here's an example:

**DataModel**: This exposes data manipulation methods to local code. Here its just using in-memory data structures, but in real applications, it can be backed by a database or a web service or something else.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class DataModel {
    private static DataModel ourInstance = new DataModel();

    private final List<String> mPersons;
    private final HashMap<String,Set<String>> mGroups;

    public static DataModel getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    private DataModel() {
        mPersons = new ArrayList<String>();
        mGroups = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
            mPersons.add("person_"+i);
        }
    }

    public void updateGroup(String oldName, String newName, Set<String> members){
        assert  newName != null && !newName.isEmpty() && members != null : "data must not be null or empty";

        if(oldName != null){
            mGroups.remove(oldName);
        }

        mGroups.put(newName, members);
    }

    public void deleteGroup(String name){
        mGroups.remove(name);
    }

    public boolean isMember(String groupName, String memberName){
        return mGroups.containsKey(groupName) && mGroups.get(groupName).contains(memberName);
    }

    public List<String> getGroups(){
        List<String> groups = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String s : mGroups.keySet()){
            groups.add(s);
        }

        return groups;
    }

    public List<String> getMembersOf(String groupName){
        List<String> members = new ArrayList<String>();

        if(mGroups.containsKey(groupName)){
            members.addAll(mGroups.get(groupName));
        }

        return members;
    }

    public List<String> getPersons(){
        List<String> persons = new ArrayList<String>();
        persons.addAll(mPersons);
        return persons;
    }
}
```

**Activity to List data**: Allows action mode by long clicking any item, or edit an item by clicking on it.

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GroupActivity extends ListActivity implements AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    public static final int REQ_CODE_EDIT_GROUP = 101;

    private List<String> mSelection;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mSelection = new ArrayList<String>();
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1);

        mAdapter.addAll(DataModel.getInstance().getGroups());

        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        getListView().setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        getListView().setMultiChoiceModeListener(this);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    private void refresh(){
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(DataModel.getInstance().getGroups());
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem item = menu.add("New");
        item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getTitle().equals("New")){
            startEditor(null);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void startEditor(String groupName){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,EditorActivity.class);

        if(groupName != null){
            i.putExtra(EditorActivity.KEY_EDIT_GROUP,groupName);
        }

        startActivityForResult(i,REQ_CODE_EDIT_GROUP);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode actionMode, int i, long l, boolean checked) {
        if(checked){
            mSelection.add(mAdapter.getItem(i));
        }else {
            mSelection.remove(mAdapter.getItem(i));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
        MenuItem item = menu.add("Delete");
        item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
        if(menuItem.getTitle().equals("Delete")){

            for (String groupName : mSelection){
                DataModel.getInstance().deleteGroup(groupName);
            }

            refresh();
            actionMode.finish();
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
        mSelection.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(requestCode == REQ_CODE_EDIT_GROUP && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            refresh();
        }else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        String groupName = mAdapter.getItem(i);
        startEditor(groupName);
    }
}
```

**Activity to edit data** : Allows editing names and selections etc.

It has a Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<EditText
     android:id="@+id/edit"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="Group name"
     android:inputType="text"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And Activity code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.*;

import java.util.HashSet;


public class EditorActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String KEY_EDIT_GROUP = "edit_group";

    private EditText mNameEdit;
    private ListView mListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private String mOldGroupName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editor);

        mNameEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        mListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1);
        mAdapter.addAll(DataModel.getInstance().getPersons());
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mOldGroupName = getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_EDIT_GROUP);

        if(mOldGroupName != null){
            mNameEdit.setText(mOldGroupName);

            for (int i = 0 ; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++){
                DataModel dm = DataModel.getInstance();
                String member = mAdapter.getItem(i);

                if(dm.isMember(mOldGroupName,member)){
                    mListView.setItemChecked(i,true);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem item = menu.add("Done");
        item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getTitle().equals("Done")){

            String newGroupName = mNameEdit.getText().toString();

            if(newGroupName == null || newGroupName.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Invalid group name",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
            }

            HashSet<String> selectedMembers = new HashSet<String>();
            for (int i = 0 ; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++){
                if(mListView.isItemChecked(i)){
                    selectedMembers.add(mAdapter.getItem(i));
                }
            }

            DataModel.getInstance().updateGroup(mOldGroupName,newGroupName,selectedMembers);

            setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I tried but not working...Here is my code



             for (int c = 0 ; c < checked.size(); c++){
                 if(checked.get(c,false)){
                     arr2.remove(c);
                 }
             }

             adapter2.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

Comment: @AnilBhatiya Can you post the code where you set list view to use  choice mode ?

Comment: adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), R.layout.single_row, R.id.txt,arr2);
    lvDialog.setAdapter(adapter2);
    lvDialog.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: It's dynamic List view as data are coming from user input

Comment: Now I have to ask one more question to you...How can I do it for multiple items in listview?

Comment: @AnilBhatiya The example provided is already multi-choice: `list.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)`. You can select any number of items and remove them in one go.

Comment: can you come in chat session?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34503/discussion-between-s-d-and-anil-bhatiya)